# Git reset branch to master

Tags: git, branch, reset

I have created a branch for example with branch name branch1.
I made some change to files, folders and also I have some untracked files. Only local, no adds or commit.

Now I want to return to origin/master so I can make the steps again from the beginning( trying to solve a problem in my site).
I am thinking of these:
git clean -f to clean all untracked files, 
git reset -hard to clean the branch, 
git branch -d branch_name, 
and in the end switch to master branch and pull files.

My real scenario is: I am having a online site with two servers. One for production and one for development. They are using my git.
I made a new branch as I described. Then I run some scripts which were created some new untracked files and modified some other files. This didn't go right but I found the solution. So I want to return back to master and make the steps again from scratch.
As I said all changes made in the development server locally. No adds or commits are made.

Am I missing something please? I don't want to mess up my git

Comment: you want to discard completely your changes on branch1 and move back to master?

Comment: Exactly. I want to start again from my master files. With new branch

Comment: you may loose everything from branch1?

Comment: I don't care to lost the changes. I just want to return to previous files and start my edits again. From original files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all untracked files with:

```
git clean --force
```

Removed all unstaged changes with:

```
git reset --hard
```

Go back to master branch with:

```
git checkout master
```

Then make and switch to a new branch with:

```
git checkout -b <newBranchName>
```

'git checkout master' will bring your files back to the state they were in on master. Since all edits were done on your local machine, there's no need to do a pull.

'git checkout -b ...' makes and switches you to a new branch so any changes you want to make will be on that new branch based on master.

Comment: After checkout master, I must pull the files from master, right? And then create the new branch...?

Comment: If no pushes to origin/master have been made, then 'git pull' is not required. 'git pull' just downloads refs from remote branch and merges them with your local branch.

Comment: the is a good question, do you need to update your master first?

Comment: Nope. I don't want to update my master. I will edit my first post with my real scenario for you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git reset --hard # get back you the last commit you worked from

git checkout -b new_branch master # create a new branch from master and switch to
```

then

```
git clean -fd # remove everything that is not known by git
```

Comment: git clean removes everything that is not committed and not tracked; this brings you in a state almost like a git clone

Comment: Thank you OznOg. git clean understood. But I am confused with git checkout  -b new_branch master. This return the files to original without you have to pull them?

Comment: this creates a new branch taking master as the base commit (start at the point where is master)

Comment: git clean -fd removed everything that is not known by git....I didn't pay attention to this OznOg and I forgot to tell you that master branch because of my site's platform had excluded from git two folders....And I lost them

Comment: OznOg you are right! I didn't pay attention to my original setup....That's fine....I will move the deleted folder from my backup. What should I do so it won't happen again?

Comment: my advice it ALWAYS COMMIT every thing you think worthful, even if you this this may not be useful at the moment. I is always easier to find an old commit than rewriting everything... Next, when you feel unconfortable with a manipulation, perform a real backup first (tar.gz of the directory). This is usually useless if you know what you do with git, but can save you ass-ets when you make a mistake... sorry for that bad experience.. I should have suggest the backup to...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182680/discussion-between-g-g-and-oznog).

Comment: sorry, time to go for me... maybe tomorrow